# How to set different color bars to each facet?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, scale, facet

[At present it look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PXoj.png)

I want to draw a series of grid plot with different color bars for different facets because the variables shown by different facets has different magnitude. But it seems could only set a single color bar for all facets thus my plot could only look like this.

And this is the kind of plot what I like.
[The kind of plot I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu31A.jpg)

Comment: First, plot your charts one by one. Then, use `grid.arrange` in `gridExtra` library to put all your charts together.

Comment: It works. Though I use matplotlib in the end.